# How do I get R to ignore N/A values without having it delete the whole row?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am working on a big dataset (around 40 column) and I need to aggregate the values of different column by months, averaging the values inside the month. 
The dataset looks something like this.

```
dd <-
mo  yr Na   NH4 NO2
1 2009 0.4  N/A N/A
1 2009 0.2  0.1 N/A
2 2009 0.5  0.6 0.4
2 2009 0.7  0.2 0.1
```

I've used

```
dd.agg=aggregate(.~mo+yr, dd, FUN=mean)
```

to create a new dataset, but since I have some N/A datas (and I can't remove them or change them into 0s because they are due to some problem in the sampling procedure) in the NO2 column, the whole month of January is removed from the dd.agg dataset. I've tried to add na.rm=TRUE, but it doesn't seem to help.

What I need is, essentially, for R to just ignore the presence of the N/A data. Not to treat them like 0s (it would affect the average) but to obtain from that dataset something like this

```
dd.agg <-
mo  yr Na   NH4 NO2
1 2009 0.3  0.1 N/A
2 2009 0.6  0.4 0.25
```

Where if a whole month is comprised of N/As the average is just a N/A value (or an empty cell, it doesn't really matter to me since I don't need them in the plots) and when a month has just a couple of N/As, to average the non N/As value. 
I could do row by row the same aggregate procedure and then put everything inside a new dataset manually, but for 40 column is a bit of a pain... 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `na.action = na.pass`

```
aggregate(.~mo+yr, dd, FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
#   mo   yr  Na NH4  NO2
#1  1 2009 0.3 0.1  NaN
#2  2 2009 0.6 0.4 0.25
```

---

With `tidyverse`, this can be done with

```
library(tidyverse)
dd %>% 
    group_by(mo, yr) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

NOTE: `N/A` is not regarded as `NA` in `R`.  It should be first converted to `NA` before attempting this

While reading the data with `read.table/read.csv`, specify the elements that are going to be `NA` with `na.strings`

```
dd <- read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = "N/A")
```

#### data

```
dd <- structure(list(mo = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), yr = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
 2009L), Na = c(0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7), NH4 = c(NA, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2
 ), NO2 = c(NA, NA, 0.4, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Here, we specify as `NA` because `N/A` is a string and this can change the column type of `character` or `factor` depending on the way it was read (`stringsAsFactors` - option)