# R won't compute means correctly with aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

Not sure why R won't calculate the means of my data correctly. I do have a lot of NA values but R keeps telling me that the mean is NA. Here's an example:

```
data1=read_excel"pepper.xlsx"

data1$cultivar = as.factor(data1$cultivar)

mean = aggregate(data1[,3:4], list(data1$cultivar), mean)
```

| cultivar | replication | width | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOF | 1 | 12 | 14 |
| BOF | 2 | 10 | NA |
| BOF | 3 | NA | 15 |
| BOF | 4 | NA | NA |

Instead of computing the mean width of `BOF` being 11 and the mean `height` being 14.5, it computes the means of the height and width as NA. This is an over-simplification of my data. I have several cultivars in my study and calculated the means of each variable of each cultivar using the `aggregate` function.

Comment: `mean` has an argument `na.rm` to remove missing values. Add `na.rm = TRUE` as an argument. See `?mean` for details.

Comment: Also, be careful of your phrasing - "R won't compute means correctly" sounds as if you think there's a bug in R. "How do I ignore missing values in `mean`" is a much more politic way to phrase the issue.

Comment: `aggregate(.~cultivar, data1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you! this solved my problem. Sorry about the wording but thanks for the heads up. I've never coded before and I'm expected to teach myself R to analyze my data for my graduate program. Hope I don't get too much backlash from this community if I phrase something or do anything incorrectly by accident. Just here to learn!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701560/how-do-i-get-r-to-ignore-n-a-values-without-having-it-delete-the-whole-row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get R to ignore N/A values without having it delete the whole row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701560/how-do-i-get-r-to-ignore-n-a-values-without-having-it-delete-the-whole-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
There is no need for anonymous function (Credits to Gregor Thomas, see comments). We could use:

```
summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**First answer:**
Thanks to Gregor Thomas `colMeans`won't work here.
We could use `dplyr` package `summarise` and `across`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(cultivar) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Output:

```
  cultivar replication width height
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 BOF              2.5    11   14.5
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the groupings that `aggregate` does... that's my guess as to why you're drawing downvotes.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas. Thank you for this tip. Please see my edit!

Comment: You don't need an anonymous function here, you can simplify to `summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks to Gregor Thomas. I have updated the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mean = aggregate(data1[,3:4], list(data1$cultivar), mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
```